# React Native: Get Value of PlatformColor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to provide a color to a function in my app in the form of a string, I would like to use a system color and therefore, I am using the PlatformColor API. This seems to return an object rather than a string. Is there any way to extract a string representation of this color returned by the API?

Comment: can you please add your code, so that we can check what is the issue and what alternative approach we can take?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same question here. I don't believe this question needs code. What it needs is a React Native expert who knows the answer.